# How to test Rails 5 application with Mongoid using fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, fixtures

I commonly use a mix of Fixtures and Factories to test Rails ActiveRecord applications.

Now I have a new application that uses Mongoid.  What is the best method of loading static fixture data to test the app using Mongoid and rspec?  There does not appear to be any active gems in this area.

Comment: I am only aware of fixtures in Rails context (early Rails core members seem to have in particular been in favor of fixtures over factories). As such fixtures are tied to ActiveRecord as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/nycjv321/mongoid_fixtures

Not perfect by any means, I had to fork it and modify it to get it to work and get rid of some warnings, but I've found no alternatives.

My fork, just in case: https://github.com/esquinas/mongoid_fixtures